# Function works in playground but not in XCode test

Tags: swift, xcode, concurrency

I have a function that fetches data from a URL:

```swift
private func fetch(url: URL) -> String? {
    var htmlString: String?
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            return
        }
        if let mimeType = httpResponse.mimeType, mimeType == "text/html",
           let data = data,
           let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            htmlString = string
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    
    return htmlString
}
```

This function works in a playground, when I test it as part of a package in XCode, it doesn't seem to run past the `let task...` statement. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you aware you are in an async context here? `return htmlString` runs before your network call completes.

Comment: So do I mark this function with `async` and call it with `await` in my test (and wherever else I use it)? Sorry, I am very new to Swift.

Comment: This question is most probably a duplicate, so I won´t write an answer. But you are right, `async/await` is the way to go nowadays. Google will be your friend here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataTask` rendition that returns the result immediately would only work if your device happened to have a cached response ready to deliver. Otherwise, it would `return` before the `dataTask` had a chance to complete.

One needs to wait for the response from the server before returning the result. In Swift concurrency, we would `await`:

```swift
enum WebError: Error {
    case notSuccess(Int)
    case notHtml
}

private func fetch(url: URL) async throws -> String? {
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
    }
    
    guard 200...299 ~= response.statusCode else {
        throw WebError.notSuccess(response.statusCode)
    }
    
    guard
        response.mimeType == "text/html",
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) 
    else {
        throw WebError.notHtml
    }

    return string
}
```

Note, I also throw errors, so that if something goes wrong, the caller can `catch` the error and successfully diagnose what went wrong.

---

See WWDC 2021 video [Use async/await with URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10095/).